# Вывод списка в алфавитном порядке (Классы в Java)

Tags: java, классы

По заданию необходимо вывести список людей в алфавитном порядке.
Необходимо использовать классы. 2 задания сделал и осталось только вывод. Но как сделать - не понимаю. Листинг программы прилагаю. Заранее большое спасибо!

Элементы в которых не знаю что писать и как это реализовать

```
        System.out.println("\n Люди в алфавитном порядке :");
        List<Settings> listSortByFamilia = phone.getListByFamilia(); //Что необходимо написать в скобках?
        for (Settings c : listSortByFamilia) {
            System.out.println(c);
        }
```

```
    //Тут надо вывод по алфавиту
    List<Settings> getListByFamilia(int Familia) {
        List<Settings> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Settings c : PhoneList) {

        }
        return list;
    }
```

Полный код программы:

```
package com.company;
import java.util.*;

import static java.util.Collections.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Phone phone = new Phone("phone");
        phone.addApartmentList(new Settings("Иванов", "Иван", "Иванович", "Ленина 22", 5251, 1, 2, 60.2, 0));
        phone.addApartmentList(new Settings("Петров", "Петр", "Петрович", "Гагарина 44", 523124, 1, 2, 48, 50.1));
        phone.addApartmentList(new Settings("Васильев", "Василий", "Васильевич", "Павловича 66", 52712124, 1, 2, 0, 0));
        phone.addApartmentList(new Settings("Сидоров", "Сидор", "Сидорович", "Васильково 88", 363412124, 1, 2, 0, 236));
        phone.addApartmentList(new Settings("Григорьев", "Григорий", "Григорьевич", "Пионерская 100", 97712124, 1, 2, 11, 0));

        System.out.println("\n Время внутригородских разговоров больше 15:");
        List<Settings> listSortByTimeVnutr = phone.getListByTimeVnutr(15);
        for (Settings c : listSortByTimeVnutr) {
            System.out.println(c);
        }

        System.out.println("\n Данные о тех кто пользовался междугородним телефоном:");
        List<Settings> listSortByTimeVnesh = phone.getListByTimeVnesh(0);
        for (Settings c : listSortByTimeVnesh) {
            System.out.println(c);
        }

        System.out.println("\n Люди в алфавитном порядке :");
        List<Settings> listSortByFamilia = phone.getListByFamilia(?); //ЧТО ТУТ ПИСАТЬ
        for (Settings c : listSortByFamilia) {
            System.out.println(c);
        }

//Тут надо вывод по алфавиту
    }
}
class Phone {
    private String PhoneType;
    private ArrayList<Settings> PhoneList = new ArrayList<>();

    Phone(String HouseType) {
        this.PhoneList = PhoneList;
    }

    void addApartmentList(Settings Settings) {
        PhoneList.add(Settings);
    }

//Функции для вывода по условию

    List<Settings> getListByTimeVnutr(double TimeVnutr) {
        List<Settings> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Settings c : PhoneList) {
            if (TimeVnutr<(c.getTimeVnutr())) {
                list.add(c);
            }
        }
        return list;
    }

    List<Settings> getListByTimeVnesh(double TimeVnesh) {
        List<Settings> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Settings c : PhoneList) {
            if (TimeVnesh!=(c.getTimeVnesh())) {
                list.add(c);
            }
        }
        return list;
    }

    //Тут надо вывод по алфавиту
    List<Settings> getListByFamilia(int Familia) {
        List<Settings> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Settings c : PhoneList) {

        }
        return list;
    }


}

class Settings {
    {
        idGenerator++;
    }

    private static int idGenerator = 0;
    private int id = idGenerator;
    private String Familia;
    private String Imia;
    private String Otchestvo;
    private String Adress;
    private int NomerKard;
    private int Debet;
    private int Kredit;
    private double TimeVnutr;
    private double TimeVnesh;

    Settings(String Familia, String Imia, String Otchestvo, String Adress, int NomerKard, int Debet, int Kredit, double TimeVnutr, double TimeVnesh) {
        this.Familia = Familia;
        this.Imia = Imia;
        this.Otchestvo = Otchestvo;
        this.Adress = Adress;
        this.NomerKard = NomerKard;
        this.Debet = Debet;
        this.Kredit = Kredit;
        this.TimeVnutr = TimeVnutr;
        this.TimeVnesh = TimeVnesh;
    }
    public String getFamilia() {
        return Familia;
    }
    public double getTimeVnesh() {
        return TimeVnesh;
    }
    public double getTimeVnutr() {
        return TimeVnutr;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("\n" + "Familia: %s\t Imia: %s\t Otchestvo: %s \t Adress: %s\t NomerKard: %s\t Debet: %s\t Kredit: %s\t TimeVnutr: %s\t TimeVnesh: %s\t",
                 Familia, Imia, Otchestvo, Adress, NomerKard, Debet, Kredit, TimeVnutr, TimeVnesh);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Изменил ваш код тут

```
System.out.println("\n Люди в алфавитном порядке :");
List<Settings> listSortByFamilia = phone.getListByFamilia(); //ЧТО ТУТ ПИСАТЬ
```

и тут

```
// Тут надо вывод по алфавиту
  List<Settings> getListByFamilia() {
    List<Settings> list = (ArrayList) PhoneList.clone();
    list.sort(
        (a, b) -> {
          return a.getFamilia().compareTo(b.getFamilia());
        });
    return list;
  }
```

Попробуйте посмотреть что получилось

Comment: Спасибо! Работает!

Comment: @Алексей если ответ помог то можете пометить как полезный